# frequency and selection of mcu

Tags: microcontroller, frequency

I am looking at migrating from a MCU of 200MHz to one of a lower frequency/clock speed. Now, I want to justify my action or rather do a feasability study. To explain that my descision to migrate to a slower MCU is justified and thereby helping reduce price and also ,in all likelyhood reduce EMI emmision and power consumption.

How can I go about such a study. My initial MCU(200MHz) is the LPC4337 from NXP. It is a dual M0/M4 core which runs an FFT.
A straightforward method would be to migrate/write the same code for a lower speed MCU and then see/compare the executioon time for both controllers. But that seems very basic. Is there any other parameters on which I can base such a study on ?

The MCU I would like to migrate to is the RPC564A80 from ST Micro. probably it could be costly, but I am merely interested in the processing power. Ofcourse , on a straight foirward glance, the LPC can run at a higher speed. But probably for my code such a speed might be an overkill. What is the test pattern I should follow to justify(from a frequency point,power and other factors are secondary)

Comment: Do you need to migrate? Underclocking is probably much easier. Even if there are other considerations like CPU cost, it can experimentally make the case that lower speed operation works ... or not.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand **why** you want to migrate. "reduce price and reduce EMI and power comsumption" you state in the first paragraph, then you select a MCU which has a state of "proposal" so in all likelihood will never get manufactured. You say it (the MCU?) might be costly but you are merely interested in processing power. Then you ask about a test pattern from a frequency standpoint and other factors are secondary. So what are you really looking for? (just a note: a MCU is not forced to run at it's maximum frequency, the µA/MHz tend to get lower but that's all)

Comment: And the very basic approach of testing how your code will perform on both and compare it, is actually a quite good one, sure you don't have time to optimize every µs out of it, but you have measurements you can trust (instead of doing some fortune telling based on some datasheets which are wrong).

Comment: I would caution against the mentality of using a slower CPU or in otherwords, going against what the market place has to offer as you may design yourself into a corner forcing a premature redesign (of what is available/cost effective instead of what is neither).

Comment: Also, unless there is a specific errata in the datasheet regarding EMC for the micro itself (and it does happen), I would say the PCB layout/EMC mitigation techniques should be the first avenue to investigate.